# How to create a plugin for take a backup of speific table in wordpress database?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Actually i download a plugin .This Plugin create some new tables in my word press database.Now i need to create a another plugin for to take a backup of table & data in that table created by the plugin i down loaded .(eg: i download a plugin name "b" and i activate it.It create table1,table2 table 3 in my wordpress site database. I worked in that plug in store some data s in table1 ,table2,table3 etc.I create a other plug in and it is linked to the downloaded plugin & now 
I need to take a backup of table1,table2 table 3 .I have a form in my php page ,when clicking submit button on the form then the backup of selected table is stored to my computer as .sql or .sql zip file.Ineed the code)  .

Please suggest if any one know the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of plugins for Wordpress that creates backups of your WP database. One of those I use is [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall/), because it has a lot of security stuff plus the DB backup tool. If you want a more specific plugin you have [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/backupwordpress/), for example. This two plugins has a support and they're very reliable.

Comment: I see that plugin already .It is an excellent plugin. But i need to create my own plugin .So i asked Doubt here. Thanks for your support .

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin to back your database or custom tables in the database
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-db-backup/

Comment: I see that plugin already .It is an excellent plugin. But i need to create my own plugin .So i asked Doubt here. Thanks for your support .

Comment: I think there is no need to create plugin because this plugin give your required functionality if you want to create plugin then i wil share a link to you the basics how to create plugin try these http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin    and  http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-wordpress-plugin-development/